# Сравнение списка и подсчет очков

Tags: java, android

Продолжаю работать над системой ачивок в игре, сделал подсчет таким образом:
Каждый String - своя задача, переменная `alen#`определяет сколько раз выполнено действие (подтягивается автоматом из статистики). Есть 5 типов заданий, но будет больше, около 20 типов, и всего более 301 заданий-ачивок.

```
    String task_1 = "Слово из 3 букв собранно " + alen_1 + " раза";
    String task_2 = "Слово из 3 букв собранно " + alen_2 + " раза";
    ...
    ...
    String task_n = "Слово из 3 букв собранно " + alen_n + " раза";
    String task_n+1 = "Слово из 3 букв собранно " + alen_n+1 + " раза";
    ...
    ...
```

Есть два листа
 `ArrayList<String> TaskDone = new ArrayList<>();` - выполненные задачи  и список всех возможных:  `ArrayList<String> LogQA = new ArrayList<>();`

Метод проверяющий правильность выполнения заданий. `int ASD` - буферная переменная для очков от ачивок. Хотел сделать более-менее универсальный метод, но выходит громоздко. Можно как-то поправить и улучшить это? Думаю, что скорей всего надо будет переносить это в БД, но пока до них не дошел:

```
    int ASD;
    public void PrintShow(){
       if (LogQA.contains(task_1)){
           TaskDone.add(task_1);
           this.asd += 3;
           LogQA.remove(task_1);
       } else if(LogQA.contains(task_2)){
           TaskDone.add(task_2);
           this.asd += 4;
           LogQA.remove(task_2);
       } 
       ...
       ...
       else{
            textTask.setText("Уже выполнено");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для хранения задач лучше завести структуру данных, скажем тот-же самый ArrayList.

```
List<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> taskDone = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> logQA = new ArrayList<>();
```

Тогда, как простейший вариант, можно в цикле пробежать по нему и свериться с TaskDone. Так будет короче.

```
for (String eachString : taskList) {
        if (logQA.contains(eachString)) {
            taskDone.add(eachString);
            logQA.remove(eachString);
        }
    }
```

PS. Пожалуйста, соблюдайте code conventions, пишите названия переменных с маленькой буквы, TaskDone.add() читается так, как будто вы хотите вызвать статический метод у класса.